# PayPal sendbox US shipping method issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

My PayPal send box account is registered with UK country. But when i tried to enter the US country address as shipment address. At that time PayPal show Shipping Address Error.

Here is screen

[image: Paypal Shipping Error]

[image]

How can i resolve this Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove shipping address detail request parameters being sent to paypal and set NO_SHIPPING=1 in request parameters.

So neither PayPal will look for shipping detail in request nor it would display shipping address fill up form to user.

let me know if you still face any issue.

Thanks